# I'm in England, and want to move to a time-of-use electricity tariff, how do I get an appropriate meter fitted?

Tags: electricity, uk

I'm in England, and currently on a single-price electricity tariff, that's measured by a (very) old-style electricity meter (mine says "property of Eastern Electricity Board" on it, so it's well over 20 years old).

After my previous question on how to decarbonise my home heating - [How can I decarbonise my domestic heating, given severe physical constraints?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/319/48) - I think my best bet is to to put in electricity storage heaters, and a hot water tank with electric immersion heaters.

If I want to move to a time-of-use tariff, such as Economy Seven, then that would require more sophisticated metering. At the very least, a second old-style meter, which has been standard practice for dwellings on Economy 7 or Economy 10 for 30-odd years.

However, Britain is just starting the process of switching from old-style meters to smart meters.

So, if I want to move to a time-of-use electricity tariff, how do I get an appropriate meter fitted, and what should I be looking for, if I want to take part in the forthcoming demand-side response market?

(I get my electricity and gas from [Ecotricity](http://ecotricity.co.uk/), if that makes a difference)

Comment: Given the current UK generation mix, wouldn't a switch from gas to electric storage heating increase the heating's carbon footprint, and probably its cost?

Comment: @SimonW . Good question, and the answer is too short to post as a comment: please do post it as a question in its own right.

Comment: done :-) 123456

Answer (score 3):

Paul from Ecotricity here.

We can certainly arrange for the meter to be exchanged to an Economy-7 meter, enabling you to have both off-peak and on-peak registers to record your electricity usage. If you have night storage heaters and a timed immersion heater, then it would be beneficial to have an off-peak style meter as you will then have the units used by these appliances charged at the lower off-peak tariff. There may be a charge for the meter upgrade though, we'll be able to confirm that before we start the work.

Regarding Smart metering, Ecotricity are waiting for the Government to begin the roll out of Smart meters. The Government, through DECC (Department of Energy and Climate Change) are going through a process of trialling meters and deciding on the final specification before suppliers can begin installing them for their customers.

Please see this following link for further information on Smart meters; https://www.gov.uk/smart-meters-how-they-work#supplier-led-roll-out

If you'd like to talk about the meter upgrade or smart meters, please give us a ring on 08000 302 302

Hope that helps?

Best regards
Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul - I'll add in more info here if I get it from that phonecall

Comment: Delighted to see somebody from Ecotricity on here!