# How do white roofs cause global warming?

Tags: solar-power, solar-thermal

Another user [asked](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/prevent-concrete-roof-from-absorbing-too-much-heat-during-summer/4343#4343) the question, and I think the question is important enough to deserve it's own post.

I've heard that white roofs drive away clouds and cause global warming. How can this be?

Comment: Not everything you hear is true.  Goes double for stuff you read on the internet.  As for example, the various attempts to create hysteria over replacing incandescent light bulbs with CFLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This counter-intuitive advice is actually the result of [research](http://news.stanford.edu/news/2011/october/urban-heat-islands-101911.html). Unfortunately journalists are rarely qualified to cover any sort of science news, and this was no exception. I'll try to explain the result in more detail, and in a way people can understand.

Most people know that dark colored objects absorb light and become warm in the sun. The darker the color, the more light objects tend to absorb. Black asphalt and dark roofs are familiar examples. When they warm in the sun, they in turn warm nearby air.

Rather than rising immediately, this warm surface air tends to get stuck under colder, heavier air. On a large scale this is called an inversion, but on small scales such things happen everyday. The warm air is less dense, and will rise given the opportunity. Most commonly a building or bare tree will provide an easy path for the warm air to rise, and this tends to pull the entire pocket of warm air into a thermal column. These columns can last minutes or hours, depending on conditions.

Thermal air columns rise until they hit the condensation point, where they stop and form white, puffy clouds (cumulus clouds).

Now consider what happens when you replace that dark roof with a very reflective white roof. Rather than heating up, the roof "reflects" solar energy right back into the atmosphere. Some of the light escapes, but much of it is absorbed by air gasses and black carbon soot. The small amount of light escaping the atmosphere would be more than offset by the clouds formed by dark roofs.

Clouds reflect light just like a white roof does, but they do so from higher in the atmosphere, and they're much larger than a roof. Overall white roofs cause more energy to stay in our atmosphere, and contribute to global warming.

*However*, if you live in a hot, sunny area where clouds never form regardless of your choice, a white roof will reflect some solar energy back into space. In this scenario, you can paint your roof white with a clean conscience.

A better alternative is to cover your roof with solar panels. This converts solar energy into electricity which you may otherwise purchase from a coal or diesel power plant. It keeps the solar energy from heating your home, and doesn't reflect as much energy back into the atmosphere. It allows clouds to form, and is the most sustainable solution. A green roof might also be a good answer, if your building is strong enough to support it.

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I think the reasoning in the linked article is different from yours. You say that solar radiation is reflected back up by white roofs and then "_absorbed by air gasses and black carbon soot._" and that "_Clouds reflect light just like a white roof does_". This seems to suggest that the air gasses, soot and clouds are absorbing more solar radiation and cause the heating up.

Comment: In the article they say that white roofs "_caused a net global warming, largely because they reduced cloudiness slightly_" and that "_the reduction in cloudiness allowed more sunlight to reach the surface_". So here the main cause is more solar radiation reaches the Earth surface. 
Which reasoning is correct?

Comment: The real point of white roofs (or "cool roofs", which need not be white) is not to reflect heat directly, but to reduce the heat absorbed by the building, and so the energy used for A/C.  Obviously the benefit differs, depending on whether you live in Phoenix or Minneapolis, where you'd get more net benefit from a dark roof heating in winter.

Comment: THelper, there are many factors to consider. The paper considered other factors that neither I nor the article even mention, such as the relationship between clouds and snow. See section 7 starting on page 21. @jamessqf, very true. What's worse, A/C is far more efficient than heat, so a short winter can counteract any benefits of a white roof during a long summer.

Comment: @Sophit: How exactly is A/C more efficient than heat?  Seems like it depends on the heat source, as (depending on where you live) heat a building through insolation, solar collectors, or a wood stove, while all practical A/C systems that I know of work on electricity.  (Other than mine, which consists of good insulation plus living where nighttime temps drop into the 50s even on the hottest days of summer.)

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the research.  Cloud physics, last I saw was still hard to simulate.  For a white roof to be a net warmer you would have to show that more cloud is created by a black roof than by a white roof.   Further you have to show that the type of cloud created is one that would contribute to cooling and not warming. Given that the current batch of GCMs have icecaps as a strong forcing agent (ice cap has high albedo -- cools the planet off) I remain skeptical.

Comment: Yes. The research link was in the article I linked above, but here it is [again](http://www.stanford.edu/group/efmh/jacobson/Articles/Others/HeatIsland+WhiteRfs0911.pdf).

Comment: @jamesqf If a heater could heat a space one temperature unit for one unit of energy, then an A/C unit remove that unit of temperature for less than one unit of energy. This breaks down as you try to move heat from a very cold space into a very hot space, but I've been impressed by A/C even in absurdly hot climates. Regardless, the point is that white roofs are a particularly bad choice in colder climates where A/C works well, and potentially a reasonable (but not ideal) choice in hot climates where A/C works less well.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is, in contributes to the planet surface albedo, it reflects light and therefore heat back into the atmosphere where it is trapped in the weather system. Whether it has real impact or not is debatable. If everyone on the planet painted their roof's white, it might increase our collective albedo by something on the order of less than 0.001 %

The effect it will have or more local, shifting the weather patterns, similar to how metro Florida where the rain clouds always rain on schedule around the cities, but no longer seem able to surmount the updraft caused by all the pavement.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Reflecting visible light back into the atmosphere does not cause it to be "trapped in the weather system".